# Is there a website listing historical visa requirements between given countries during the 20th century?

Tags: visas, online-resources, history

Let's say I want to find out what were the visa requirements between Belgium and France in 1950. Is there a website which tracks such information on historical visa requirements?

It's easy to find out what the visa requirements are *nowadays* by checking Timatic or Wikipedia, but quite hard to dig up information on what they were in past history.

Comment: I would guess that from 1963 Timatic was printed on paper and possibly some library has it or perhaps the IATA keeps copies. Once it was electronic I can't imagine anyone but the IATA keeping a versioned copy because it's very unlikely anyone but them had a full copy. Anything before that is very likely a matter of researching the archives of the relevant government bodies of the two countries.  This is way too broad. 
To order or for more information on any of the Timatic range of products please call +31 20 403 7900 or +31 20 403 7991. You can also e-mail us at customerservice.indp@iata.org

Comment: @chx I'm not asking for a list of all the visa requirements - all I want is an online resource that can tell me what they were. Surely there aren't many of those?